# Can I use pd.drop in method chaining to drop specific rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, method-chaining

I was wondering if I can used pandas `.drop` method to drop rows when chaining methods to construct a data frame.

Dropping rows is straight forward once the data frame exists:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [5, 4, 3]})
print(df1)

# drop the entries that match "2"
df1 = df1[df1['A'] !=2]
print(df1)
```

However, I would like to do this while I am creating the data frame:

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [5, 4, 3]})
        .rename(columns={'A': 'AA'})
#        .drop(lambda x: x['A']!=2)
        )
print(df2)
```

The commented line does not work, but maybe there is a correct way of doing this. Grateful for any input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [callable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [5, 4, 3]})
        .rename(columns={'A': 'AA'})
        .loc[lambda x: x['AA']!=2]
        )
```

Or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [5, 4, 3]})
        .rename(columns={'A': 'AA'})
        .query("AA != 2")
        )
print(df2)
   AA  B
0   1  5
2   3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [5, 4, 3]})
        .rename(columns={'A': 'AA'})
       .apply(lambda x: x if x['AA'] !=2 else np.nan,axis=1).dropna()
        )
print(df2)


    AA    B
0  1.0  5.0
2  3.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a selection with ".loc" at the end of your definition line code.

Comment: `import pandas as pd
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [5, 4, 3]})
        .rename(columns={'A': 'AA'})[df2['AA'] != 2]
        )
print(df2)`